# Postgresql: error "must be owner of relation" when changing a owner object

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-grant, owner

What is the `grant` option/trick I need to give to the current user ("*userA*") to allow him to change a object's owner which belongs by another user ("*userC*")?

More precisely, the *contact* table is owned by the *userC* and when I perform the following query for changing the owner to the *userB*, connected with the *userA*:

```sql
ALTER TABLE contact OWNER TO userB;
```

I get this error:

> ERROR:  must be owner of relation contact

But *userA* has all needed rights to do that normally (the "*create on schema*" grant option should be enough):

```
grant select,insert,update,delete on all tables in schema public to userA; 
grant select,usage,update on all sequences in schema public to userA;
grant execute on all functions in schema public to userA;
grant references, trigger on all tables in schema public to userA;
grant create on schema public to userA;
grant usage on schema public to userA;
```

---

Command line output:

```
root@server:~# psql -U userA myDatabase
myDataBase=>\dt contact
    List of relations
Schema |  Name   |   Type   |  Owner
-------+---------+----------+---------
public | contact | table    | userC
(1 row)
myDataBase=>
myDataBase=>alter table contact owner to userB;
ERROR:  must be owner of relation public.contact
myDataBase=>
```

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Thanks to Mike's comment, I've re-read the doc and I've realised that my current user (i.e. userA that already has the *create* privilege) wasn't a *direct/indirect member of the new owning role*...

So the solution was quite simple - I've just done this grant:

```
grant userB to userA;
```

That's all folks ;-)

---

**Update:**

Another requirement is that the object has to be owned by user *userA* before altering it...

Comment: this issue comes when we are using wrong user to do action like update/delete.i was facing this issue coz i used wrong user to do DMLs.when i chose the right user , the issue was solved.Also if you grant the DML privileges to the current user , this issue will be solved.

Comment: Just want to mention that if any user is case sensitive it should be quoted. Eg: grant "UserB" to userA -> in which case the first user is case sensitive but the second isn't

Comment: This worked for me, instead of doing `alter table ` for ownership, simply running this sorted out. I simply read this command as `grant createUser to alterUser;` where `createUser` is one who created my table and `alterUser` is one trying alter it. I faced this where we had changed DB user in our configs and DB had few existing tables.

Answer (score 26):

This solved my problem: an `ALTER TABLE` statement to change the ownership.

```
ALTER TABLE databasechangelog OWNER TO arwin_ash;
ALTER TABLE databasechangeloglock OWNER TO arwin_ash;
```

Comment: To change the ownership you need to be the owner haha

Comment: After I had super user role then I ran these commands to make myself owner on the respective objects. That allowed me to run alter, delete commands. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

From [the fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

> You must own the table to use ALTER TABLE.

Or be a database superuser.

> ERROR:  must be owner of relation contact

PostgreSQL error messages are usually spot on. This one is spot on.

Comment: The doc is more nuanced: _You *must own the table* to use ALTER TABLE. [...] To alter the owner, you *must also be a direct or indirect member of the new owning role*, and that role must have CREATE privilege on the table's schema._
=> the target user (aka. userB) has already the create priv. on the schema but my current user (aka. userA) wasn't a indirect member of the new role.
Thanks Mike to have enlightened me!

Comment: An RTFM answer, if ever I found one!

Comment: Or you can do this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27380/error-creating-index-on-postgresql-9-1

Answer (score 2):

For example, there are the users(roles) `john` and `postgres` as shown below:

```
postgres=# \dg
                             List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------
 john      |
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS
```

Then, there is `person` table whose owner is `postgres` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# \dt
         List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner
--------+--------+-------+----------
 public | person | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

Now, you can grant `postgres` to `john` with [GRANT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) as shown below:

```sql
GRANT postgres TO john;
```

*Memos:

- Be careful, granting `postgres` to `john` means `john` becomes the member of `postgres`.
- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`).

Or, you can alter `person` table's owner to `john` with [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
ALTER TABLE person OWNER TO john;
```

*Memos:

- You may also need to run one of the SQLs in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276391/why-am-i-getting-a-permission-denied-error-for-schema-public-on-pgadmin-4/77855688#77855688).
- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`).

Or, you can alter the existing user(role) `john` to a superuser with [ALTER ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-alterrole.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
ALTER ROLE john WITH SUPERUSER;
```

*Memos:

- You can omit `WITH` which is optional.
- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., postgres).
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975093/create-a-superuser-in-postgres#77260939) explains how to create a superuser in detail.

Then, `john` can alter or drop `person` table with `ALTER TABLE` or [DROP TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droptable.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
ALTER TABLE person RENAME TO student;
```

Or:

```sql
DROP TABLE person;
```

In addition, you can revoke `postgres` to `john` with [REVOKE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) as shown below:

```sql
REVOKE postgres FROM john;
```

*Memos:

- Be careful, revoking `postgres` to `john` means `john` is no more the member of `postgres`.
- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`).

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to grant the owner permissions for all tables, views and sequences:

```bash
# Tables
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';" <db_name>` ; do  psql -c "alter table \"$tbl\" owner to <db_user>" <db_name> ; done

# Views 
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select table_name from information_schema.views where table_schema = 'public';" <db_name>` ; do  psql -c "alter view \"$tbl\" owner to <db_user>" <db_name> ; done

# Sequences
for tbl in `psql -qAt -c "select sequence_name from information_schema.sequences where sequence_schema = 'public';" <db_name>` ; do  psql -c "alter sequence \"$tbl\" owner to <db_user>" <db_name> ; done
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, I had to give ownership of the complete database. and that was the case when I tried to run migrate (py manage.py migrate) in Django

how I did that, in PostgreSQL shell, please run this command:

```
ALTER DATABASE <name> OWNER TO <user>;
```