# Create a Superuser in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ubuntu, superuser

I'm looking for setup a Rails Environment with Vagrant, for that purpose the box it's been provisioned through bash shell method and includes among others this line:

`sudo -u postgres createuser <superuserusername> -s with password '<superuserpassword>'`

But I'm getting a configuration error:

> createuser: too many command-line arguments (first is "with")

Can you help me with the correct syntax for create a Superuser with a password. Thanks.

Comment: The error might be useful.

Comment: My bad, done. Do you think i'm in the correct via?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Solved with:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -s -i -d -r -l -w <<username>>
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER ROLE <<username>> WITH PASSWORD '<<password>>';"
```

I know is not an elegant solution, but for now it'll do

Answer (score 86):

Do it in a single statement within `psql`:

> CREATE ROLE username WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password';

e.g

> CREATE ROLE dummy WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD '123456';

Comment: You have to use single quotes too around the password.  Double quotes don't work.

Comment: doesn't seem to work anymore:: syntax error at or near "username"

Comment: @noone392 I just tested with `pg 14.1`, it still works.

Comment: @Eric hmm it seems to work if I put single quotes around the name with postgres 12 not sure what is going on.

Comment: @noone392 What's your username ?

Answer (score 41):

For PostgreSQL versions 8.1 and newer

To create a superuser:

```
CREATE USER username SUPERUSER;
```

If you need to specify the password:

```
CREATE USER username WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'passwordstring';
```

Comment: In PG14, I had to leave out the 'WITH', so `CREATE USER username SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'passwordstring';`

Comment: @erwaman WITH works but it has to be before. As in `CREATE USER admin WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'passwordstring';`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @AndréPena!

Answer (score 17):

To create a PostgreSQL user, follow these steps:
At the command line, type the following command as the server's root user:

```
su - postgres
```

You can now run commands as the PostgreSQL superuser.To create a user, type the following command:

```
createuser --interactive --pwprompt

At the Enter name of role to add: prompt, type the user's name.
At the Enter password for new role: prompt, type a password for the user.
At the Enter it again: prompt, retype the password.
At the Shall the new role be a superuser? prompt, type y if you want to grant superuser access. Otherwise, type n.
At the Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? prompt, type y if you want to allow the user to create new databases. Otherwise, type n.
At the Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? prompt, type y if you want to allow the user to create new users. Otherwise, type n.
```

PostgreSQL creates the user with the settings you specified.

Comment: The matter is i'm looking to create a superuser with password, through a script which executes sequentially.
                                                                                                 
`sudo -u postgres createuser postgres with password 'postgres' -s
# Set super unsafe defaultz (dev only)
sudo sh -c "echo 'local all postgres peer\nlocal all all peer\nhost all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5\nhost all all ::1/128 md5' > /etc/postgresql/10/machine/pg_hba.conf"
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload`

I'm a noob so, can you clarificate your answer? am i in the correct via?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can create the superuser `john` with the password `apple` using [CREATE ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createrole.html), [CREATE GROUP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creategroup.html) or [CREATE USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE ROLE john WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE GROUP john WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'apple';
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE USER john WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'apple';
```

*Memos:

- You can omit `WITH` which is optional.
- You must use `''` for `PASSWORD` instead of `""` otherwise there is error.
- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`).
- By default, `CREATE USER` without `LOGIN` can still have `LOGIN` attribute implicitly.
- By default, PostgreSQL needs a password so you should set `PASSWORD`.

And, you can alter the existing user(role) `john` to a superuser with [ALTER ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-alterrole.html) or [ALTER USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
ALTER ROLE john WITH SUPERUSER;
```

Or:

```sql
ALTER USER john WITH SUPERUSER;
```

*Memos:

- You can omit `WITH` which is optional.
- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`).
- [ALTER GROUP statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-altergroup.html) cannot alter an existing user(role) to a superuser.

In addition, if you want to drop the superuser `john`, first, run these SQL below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023583/how-to-quickly-drop-a-user-with-existing-privileges/77299812#77299812) explains how to drop a user(role) properly:

```sql
REASSIGN OWNED BY john TO postgres;
DROP OWNED BY john;
```

Finally, you can drop the superuser `john` with [DROP ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-droprole.html), [DROP GROUP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropgroup.html) or [DROP USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-dropuser.html) statement as shown below:

```sql
DROP ROLE john;
```

Or:

```sql
DROP GROUP john;
```

Or:

```sql
DROP USER john;
```

Answer (score -2):

CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD '12345' SUPERUSER;

In PostgreSQL, the correct syntax for creating a user with a password is slightly different.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers