# How do i install Postgres on Ubuntu and create a superuser?

Tags: postgresql

I have successfully installed Postgres on Ubuntu 20.04 by running the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

which was successful. I then run the command:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
```

which was also successful.
However, the command

```
$ sudo -u postgres createdb $USER
```

failed. The error message was as follows:

```
createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Superuser in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975093/create-a-superuser-in-postgres)

Comment: It looks like postgresql is not running. It probably starts and ends with an error. Have a look at the log-files in /var/log/postgresql

Comment: Perhaps the automagic of the Ubuntu installation packages selected a port different from 5432.