# Why am I getting a permission denied error for schema public on pgAdmin 4?

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin, permission-denied, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to view the raw data from the AACT Database in pgAdmin 4. I'm on a Mac computer. When I just try to view the first 100 rows from the 'complete_oncology' table, I get the below error:

```
ERROR: permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.complete_oncology
                      ^
SQL state: 42501
Character: 15
```

Do I have insufficient permissions? If yes, how do I grant myself permissions to view this table? I am able to see other tables from different Schemas in the AACT database. I've read some users suggest granting myself permissions with something like the below, but no luck:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON complete_oncology TO PUBLIC
```

This just turns up an error:

```
ERROR:  relation "complete_oncology" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you get a "permission denied" for `public.complete_oncology`, but a "relation does not exist" for `complete_oncology`, that can only mean only one thing: you do not have `USAGE` permissions on the `public` schema.

Get the owner of the schema to run

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO your_user;
```

Then you should be able to see the table. If you still lack permissions on the table itself, get the owner to grant you `SELECT` on the table as well.

Comment: Ah thank you, that's what I was afraid of. This schema is owned by Duke, so I sent a message off to their Contact Us form, fingers crossed someone checks it frequently haha. Thank you for your help!

Comment: this is not per se the best solution. The documentation states some ways to imrpove : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATTERNS , for example have every user have an own schema and explicitely GRANT access, unless you want PUBLIC to be the 'shared schema'.

Answer (score 122):

With PostgreSQL 15, there has been a change in the way table creation permissions are handled for users. Not directly related to pgAdmin, but I think people may run into this.

Normally, after allowing a user to CREATE tables within a database, you didn't have to specifically define that they had the permission to do that within a SCHEMA, since `public` would be the default one.

With PostgreSQL 15, this has changed ([source](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/postgresql-15-released-2526/)):

> PostgreSQL 15 also revokes the CREATE permission from all users except
> a database owner from the public (or default) schema.

So one would get the following error:

`ERROR: permission denied for schema public`

Now your flow should look like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE EXAMPLE_DB;
CREATE USER EXAMPLE_USER WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'Sup3rS3cret';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE EXAMPLE_DB TO EXAMPLE_USER;
\c EXAMPLE_DB postgres
# You are now connected to database "EXAMPLE_DB" as user "postgres".
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO EXAMPLE_USER;
```

Obviously change the privileges as you need.

The last step, where we explicitly tell that `EXAMPLE_USER` has privileges on schema `public` within `EXAMPLE_DB` is introduced in PostgreSQL 15.

Comment: This was the solution for me, I'm using PostgreSQL 15. Thank you!

Comment: It it possible to grant permission without changing the db with `\c` ?

Comment: If you're (@Hritik) talking about the GRANT on SCHEMA, then I believe no, you can only change permissions of objects of the database you're connected to. This answers clarifies a little further https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/262015

Comment: although this works, the official documentation has some other suggestions, aimed at security : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATTERNS . Granting on public basically undoes the PostgreSQL 15 security enhancements, although they have to be explicitely run. I think the better way is to have every user have an own tablespace as suggested: CREATE SCHEMA alice AUTHORIZATION alice ( default searchpath being : "$user",public  )

Comment: I get `WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"` on the last step.

Comment: @VincentGerris A good way to ensure people use enhanced security features is to make them easier to use than the relaxed ones.

Answer (score 33):

**TLDR**:

ALTER DATABASE my_database OWNER TO my_database_user;

**Justification:**
There have been recent changes to improve the security of POSTGRES depending on HOW and WHO created the database.  The long and short is now you may NEED to specify that you are also the OWNER of the database in addition to having the permissions.

**Solution**:
ALTER DATABASE my_database OWNER TO my_database_user;

Comment: Upvote this if this is useful.  It seems this has been a  breaking-change to postgres

Comment: This was the winner for me on pg15 after trying the other solutions

Comment: This works, even if you grant all privileges to the newly created database user for the said database, you should use this to specify that the newly created user is also the owner of the database. (pg15)

Comment: this worked for me on pg15 after all the privileges were already set correctly

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL 14 and in prior versions, by default anybody can create a table. but not after In PostgreSQL 15+. So the best option is to connect your database using master user of postgres database and give the grant permission. db_user is the user which require to connect your mydb database.

```
postgres=# \c mydb postgres
You are now connected to database "mydb" as user "postgres".
mydb=# GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO db_user;
GRANT
mydb=#
```

Answer (score 1):

in PostgreSQL 15, there has been a change in giving the permission. i was also facing the issue but it is now solved jus we have to do is :

Switch to the PostgreSQL User: `su postgres`
Access PostgreSQL Interactive Shell: `psql`
Connect to the Desired Database: `\c DATABASE_NAME`
Grant All Privileges on the Schema: `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO db_user;`
Exit the PostgreSQL Shell: `\q`
Restart the PostgreSQL Service:`sudo service postgresql restart`

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can grant the user `john` on `public` schema with [GRANT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) as shown below:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO john;
```

Or, you can alter `public` schema's owner to the user `john` with [ALTER SCHEMA statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterschema.html) as shown below:

```sql
ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO john;
```

Or, you can alter `apple` database's owner to the user `john` on `apple` database with [ALTER DATABASE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html) as shown below:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE apple OWNER TO john;
```

Memos:

- You can omit `PRIVILEGES` which is optional.
- You must log in with any superusers(e.g., `postgres`).

Be careful, even if you grant the user `john` on `apple` database with `GRANT` statement as shown below:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE apple TO john;
```

Then, you cannot solve the error as shown below:

```sql
apple=> CREATE TABLE person (
apple(> id INTEGER,
apple(> name VARCHAR(20)
apple(> );
ERROR:  permission denied for schema public
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE person (
                     ^
```

Answer (score -5):

1. go to preferences setting on popsql
2. connections
3. delete connection that you have
4. add new connection
   fill the form
   -connection name ( up to you)
   -Turn on Connection type "connect directly from my computer"
   -hostname : localhost (before you can type localhost, turn on the connection type "connect directly from mycomputer")
   -port : 3306
   -database name : same as you create before on cmd sql
   -username : root

Comment: The question is about PostgreSQL.  Your answer seems to relate to MySQL.