# GKE workload identity with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, gke-networking, workload-identity

I am trying to connect my spring boot application running in GKE to a cloudSQL database in GC. The suggested approach by google is via workload identity.

I have followed these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#gcloud) in addition to adding the cloud admin role to the service account and I have even run the test pod to make sure that my pod runs with the correct service account. I then run my deployment like this.

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "hello-world"
  namespace: my-dev
  labels:
    app: "hello-world"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "hello-world"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "hello-world"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "hello-container"
          image: "my-region-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo/my-tag"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
      serviceAccountName: new-service-account
      nodeSelector:
        iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: "true"
```

My understanding is that once we do that we do not need username/password to connect to the database since the service account is authorized for the connection.

However, I cannot make that work in the spring boot side. I have tried multiple combinations of from this [page](https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/cloud-services/databases/cloud-sql)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:///DATABASE_NAME?cloudSqlInstance=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory
```

and

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.*
```

properties but I have not managed to make it connect.

Is my assumption of not needing username/password wrong or is my configuration wrong?

Properties used

```
spring.datasource.username=i-am-copy-pasted@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam
spring.datasource.password=mockpassword # this is the actual value that I placed since you told me not to leave empty
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:///springdb?cloudSqlInstance=project-id:region:mydb&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&enableIamAuth=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I made it work.

First I followed the steps for [workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

You must add the service account from the workload identity to the database, that can be done both via gcloud or the console.

[Instructions how to configure database to a accept IAM authentication.](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-edit-iam-instances#configure-iam-db-instance)

Also, the database needs to have the appropriate flag, if it does not in the user section there will be an exclamation mark, if you click it you can add it.

[Instructions how to add service account to database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/add-manage-iam-users#creating-a-database-user)

So far so good, however the user does not have permissions to the database and my database is private so I cannot connect to it from outside so we have to connect via a VM in the same network to do the GRANT.

[Instructions how to execute the GRANT for a user](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-private-ip)

I followed these instructions with a small modification at the end
instead of

```
psql "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 sslmode=disable dbname=DB_NAME user=postgres"
```

you can connect without specifying a database

```
psql "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 sslmode=disable user=postgres"
```

now I just run

```
grant all privileges on database "MY_DB" to "my-service-account@my-project.iam";
```

**Beware this worked with Postgres 12, but it failed with 15 you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67276391/why-am-i-getting-a-permission-denied-error-for-schema-public-on-pgadmin-4) for 15**

Finally configure the spring boot application, according to [this guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc.md) that @Jonathan provided. I tried many dependencies, but at the end I just needed this one.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And then again as @Jonathan said the properties need to be set as following. **the password is not used, but it must not be empty!**

```
spring.datasource.username=<SHORTENED_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME>
spring.datasource.password=ANYTHING_BUT_EMPTY
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:///DATABASE_NAME?cloudSqlInstance=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&enableIamAuth=true
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your database configuration needs  Cloud SQL JDBC Connector to use IAM Authentication and workload identity.

First, add `&enableIamAuth=true` to your JDBC URL. It should look like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql:///DATABASE_NAME?cloudSqlInstance=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&enableIamAuth=true
```

Also, You will also need to set the database properties for user and password. `username` needs to be the shortened version of the Google Service Account email. `password` must not be blank or the Postgres JDBC driver will throw an exception, but because you set `enableIamAuth=true`, the password value will not be used.

```
spring.datasource.username=<SHORTENED_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME>
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Replace <SHORTENED_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME> with the shortened service account name used by your Postgres database.

You must shorten the full IAM user email into a database username. Due to
different constraints on allowed characters in the database username, Mysql and Postgres differ in how they shorten an IAM email address into a database
username.

- Mysql: Truncate the IAM email removing the `@` and everything that follows.
- Postgres: If the IAM email ends with `.gserviceaccount.com`, remove
  the `.gserviceaccount.com` suffix from the email.

For example, if the full IAM user account is
`my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, then the shortened database username
would be `my-sa` for Mysql, and `my-sa@my-project.iam` for Postgres.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work I get org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user. So it still tried to connect with username/password

Comment: I added the properties that I used in the question

Comment: Ok I had a an error in my properties, now i get boss::NOT_AUTHORIZED: Not authorized to access instance: springdb". THe problem is that the springdb is the db name not the instance name. So something is wrong with how the properties are picker up.

Comment: can it be a pom issue? I have tried, multiple configurations in the versions

Comment: I would recommend always using the most recent version of the Java connector:

Comment: As of this writing, the latest version is v1.14.1. We maintain the Github repo's documentation [jdbc.md](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc.md) with the latest version.

Comment: Other users have encountered problems using Spring Cloud GCP to configure their database connections. Try removing this library from your pom:
 `com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql`

Comment: I have gotten further. I can connect to the database but i get 

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for schema public

I need to grant access to my service account to the db but I can only see permissions for tables? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/add-manage-iam-users#creating-a-database-user

Comment: I have managed to make it work, you definitely helped me a lot, but I will write an answer entailing all the steps that I took to make it work for future users.